# How to call protocol function correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

So, I need to make notification handler class for each notification that my app received from the server. I make class like below for that purpose:

```
protocol NotificationHandlerDelegate: class {
    func receiveNotification(content: Any)
}

class NotificationHandler{

   var delegate : NotificationHandlerDelegate!

   func handleTransactionNotif(content: Any, rootVC: UIViewController){

       delegate?.receiveNotification(content: content)
       ((rootVC as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! UITabBarController).selectedIndex = 3

   }


}
```

And below is how I called it on my view controller:

```
class TransactionsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, TransactionsCellDelegate, NotificationHandlerDelegate{

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       let nh = NotificationHandler()
       nh.delegate = self

       self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
   }


   func receiveNotification(content: Any) {
       print("called: \(content)")
       let contentJSON = JSON(content)
       goToScreenAccording(to: "\(contentJSON["status"])", selectedData: content as! [String: Any])
   }

}
```

the problem is that **receiveNotification** not called whenever I receive notification. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: it looks ok, but what is calling `handleTransactionNotif`?

Comment: I called handleTransactionNotif from AppDelegate whenever I receive notification

Comment: like Scriptable said, it looks ok. What is your question?

Comment: @T.Werb take a look at edited question

Comment: I think you are using two different instances of NotificationHandler

Comment: It looks like you want your `NotificationHandler` to be a singleton

Comment: If your `delegate` variable is going be an `implicitly unwrapped optional`, then you don't need the `?` in `delegate?.receiveNotification(content: content)`.

Comment: It is possible that you TransactionsViewController is not loaded at the time you trigger your delegate. 
2. like damiancesar mentioned, if you implicitly unwrap your delegate you dont the the "?". Another option is to store you delegate property weak to prevent strong reference cycles

Comment: @damiancesar I got "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I take out the "?"

Comment: @T.Werb I tried using weak but receiveNotification still not called

Comment: Are you calling `handleTransactionNotif()` in the `AppDelegate`?

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra If you enexpectedly found nil when you delete the "?" this means your delegate property is not instantiated at the time you try to trigger your delegate.

Comment: @damiancesar yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NotificationHandler as singleton, so you can refer to the same instance:

```
class NotificationHandler {

   weak var delegate: NotificationHandlerDelegate?

   static let shared = NotificationHandler()

   private init(){}

   func handleTransactionNotif(content: Any, rootVC: UIViewController){

       delegate?.receiveNotification(content: content)
   ((rootVC as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! UITabBarController).selectedIndex = 3

   }
}

class TransactionsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, TransactionsCellDelegate, NotificationHandlerDelegate{

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       let nh = NotificationHandler.shared
       nh.delegate = self
       self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
   }
   //...
}
```

And remember to use NotificationHandler.shared in AppDelegate too.

Comment: Show me your AppDelegate implementation ;)

Comment: I called it like "NotificationHandler.sharedInstance.handleTransactionNotif(content: notification.request.content.userInfo["content"]!, rootVC: self.window!.rootViewController!)" on AppDelegate

Comment: this is actually working for me, but I need to place "delegate?.receiveNotification(content: content)" after moving the UITabBar. Thanks a lot for the help